# How to make DropDownList automatically be selected based on the Label.Text

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `DropDownlist` in the `GridView`, which should be visible only when edit is clicked. I have bound the `DropDownList` from code behind. When I click on Edit, the label value of that cell should automatically get selected in the `DropDownList`.

The code I have tried is:

```
protected void GridView3_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Location_Name FROM Location_Table");
            DropDownList bind_drop = (e.Row.FindControl("DropList") as DropDownList);
            bind_drop.DataSource = this.ExecuteQuery(cmd, "SELECT");
            bind_drop.DataTextField = "Location_Name";
            bind_drop.DataValueField = "Location_Name";
            bind_drop.DataBind();

            string Loc_type = (e.Row.FindControl("id2") as Label).Text.Trim();               
            bind_drop.Items.FindByValue(Loc_type).Selected = true;
        }
    }
```

When I run the code, it gives an exception error **Object reference not set** in the last line of the above code.
Cannot find out whats wrong. Kindly help

Comment: You should show us the relevant part of the GridView. Why don't you use `e.Row.DataItem` instead and why are you selecting all locations for every `GridViewRow`?

Comment: The error is most likely because the value you have in `Loc_type` is not a value in the select list.  Could also be due to `e.Row.FindControl("id2")` not finding a control with that ID.  Same with `e.Row.FindControl("DropList")`.

Comment: @Gromer I have made sure `Loc_type` is item in the list. And I have used the exact IDs as what I have used in the aspx code. I crossed check again.

Answer (score 1):

You must ensure that your list contains label value.

```
var index = DropDownList1.Items.IndexOf(Loc_type );
if(index > 0)
{
  DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = index;
}
else
{
  Console.WriteLine("item does not exist");
}
```